# Using Firebase with Azure Functions

Tags: typescript, firebase, azure-functions

I am working on a project where azure functions will be used as middleware to connect the frontend to a firebase backend. Azure functions should handle authenticating users via firebase auth, CRUD actions with firestore.
However, I'm having problems grasping how to do some things.

1. Do I need to initialize firebase app in every azure function call?
2. How do i check if the user is authenticated and can change the data in the firebase.
3. I might have more questions that I'm not even aware of right now.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!